# What is the use for a constructor take the same type as a parameter? Java

Tags: java, constructor

Something like this:

```
Class Object{

    Object(Object obj){}

}
```

When do you need to do that? I just like to know an example or two.

Comment: You could use that as a "copy constructor" for cloning an object. This is an example : http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12

Comment: Sometimes you need another object to build a new object. i.e. the new object doesn't make any sense without one you have already created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly used for copy constructor. An example can be as follows:

> Like C++, Java also supports copy constructor. But, unlike C++, Java
>   doesn’t create a default copy constructor if you don’t write your own.

```
class Complex {

    private double re, im;

    // A normal parametrized constructor
    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    // copy constructor
    Complex(Complex c) {
        System.out.println("Copy constructor called");
        re = c.re;
        im = c.im;
    }
    ...
```

You can refer [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-java/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This can be an effective way of duplicating an existing object or modifying one slightly.

I once worked on a Checkers board game project where `Board` and `Move` were represented as classes. In order to create a new game board the class `Board` had a constructor that accepted another `Board` instance as well as a `Move` instance. The constructor made a new game board that would exist if the `Move` had been applied to the original board.

That is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when a class needs to return an object of its own type when made.

```
class Player{
    int jerseyNumber;
    Player(){

    }
    Player (Player p){
        this.jerseyNumber = p.getJerseryNumber();
    }

    int getJerseryNumber(){
        return jerseyNumber;
    }
void setJerseyNumber(int jerseyNumber){
    this.jerseyNumber = jerseyNumber;
}
}
```

And you can do this.

```
Player ponting;
ponting.setJerseyNumber(14);
Player somebodyelse(ponting);
```

This helps **to make a new object from properties of existing one**. So basically this is called Copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's what you should know about following code:

```
class Object{

    Object(Object obj){}

}
```

Class `Object` has a constructor which takes a argument of class of type `Object`.
You can use `Object` as following:

```
class MainClass{
 public static void main(String args[]){
    Object obj=new Object(new Object());
  }
}
```

Here an anonymous object of `Object` class is passed to `Object` constructor.